# Copy Image from UIImageView into UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I wish to copy an image from the UIImageView to UIView.

I have written the swipe gesture for the UIImageView to select images and need to know how to duplicate multiple images from UIImageView to UIView when user click the Add button. I want user to be able to duplicate different image into the UIView. I will be able to arrange it later.

```
- (IBAction)handleSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    //NSLog(@"swipe");

    NSArray *images=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     @"all_LE2_Series_capacitor.jpg",
                     @"all_LE2_Series_inductor.jpg",
                     @"all_LE2_Series_msline.jpg",
                     @"all_LE2_Series_resistor.jpg",
                     @"all_LE2_Short_stub.jpg", nil];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender direction];

    switch (direction){
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft: imageIndex++;
            break;
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight: imageIndex--;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    imageIndex = (imageIndex < 0) ? ([images count] -1):
    imageIndex % [images count];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];
}

- (IBAction)Add:(UIButton *)sender {
    dropTarget.center = imageView.center;
    [self.view addSubview:dropTarget];
}
```

GUI Design

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by: "copy images from `UIImageView` to `UIView` with value attached"?

Comment: which attached value?

Answer (score 1):

To change UIView background image you can use

```
myview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:myimage];
```

Comment: I don't want to change the background and it's also out of UIView size

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on this:

**First,** you are unnecessarily adding images in your `images` array every time inside `handleSwipe:`. Make `images` a class level property and add your images once, probably in `loadView:` method.

**Next,** keep hold on to your current `imageIndex`. Move this to class level property if not already there.

**Finally,** in your view, add your selected image like this:

```
UIImageView *selectedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.images[self.imageIndex]];
[self.view addSubView:selectedImageView]
```

Comment: The error are as follow:
Property 'imageIndex' not found on object of type "ViewController".
No visible @interface for 'UIView' declare the selector 'addSubView'.

Comment: You need to create a class level property like this `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger imageIndex;` to be able to use it. I thought you were already doing that.

Comment: Sorry, the error is: Property 'images' not found on object of type 'ViewController'. and the second error is :No visible @interface for 'UIView' declare the selector 'addSubView'

Comment: I wish to add multiple image into the UIView not just one image